# TextInputLayout with floating lables on white background Visibility issue in andorid

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I am creating the simple login screen having textimputlayout floating labels.
The java file and xml is given below.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_send_cryptocurrency);
        // get the reference of View's
        emailTextInputLayout = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.emailTextInputLayout);
        passwordTextInputLayout = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.passwordTextInputLayout);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailEditText);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordEditText);
        signIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signInButton);
// perform click event on sign In Button
        signIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (validate(email, emailTextInputLayout) && validate(password, passwordTextInputLayout)) {
//  display a Thank You message
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Thank You", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }
        });
    }

    // validate fields
    private boolean validate(EditText editText, TextInputLayout textInputLayout) {
        if (editText.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
            return true;
        }
        editText.requestFocus(); // set focus on fields
        textInputLayout.setError("Please Fill This.!!!"); // set error message
        return false;
    }
```

and the xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:android.support.design="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<!-- first TextInputLayout -->
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/emailTextInputLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android.support.design:counterMaxLength="3">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/emailEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Email Id" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
<!-- first TextInputLayout -->

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/passwordTextInputLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Password">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/passwordEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
<!-- sign In Button -->
<Button
    android:id="@+id/signInButton"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="Sign In"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

and the screen shot is[image: In this image the field of the edit text is not visible.]

I have searched and tried a lot for edit text visibilty but not finding any proper reason when i give the background to xml file like any color it displays. But in the white background it is not visible . Please guide me for the mentioned issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can change color of floating labels using theme, just add below code in your styles.xml

```
<style name="TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
</style>
```

And then apply this theme to you TextInputLayout

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColorHint="@color/gray"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/hint" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```